# Calling MessageBox from a separate thread in Visual C++ 2010

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I am creating a form based Visual C++ (pre CLI I believe) application using MFC.

When the user clicks a button, I kick off a separate thread using the AfxBeginThread function.

I have a try/catch block in that thread that I want to prompt the user with a MessageBox if the exception is thrown.

When I code the MessageBox in an MFC member function, there are no syntax errors, but when I code MessageBox in the function that AfxBeginThread calls, it does not like the capital L in front of the strings, and it doesn't recognize MB_ICONEXCLAMATION definition.

For example:

```
//This compiles just fine
void CMyDialogDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    AfxBeginThread(populateFilesThread,this);
    MessageBox(L"Cool, everything is okay", L"Title", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);

}
//This won't compile, and I am afraid it wouldn't work anyway because it isn't from the main thread
void populateFilesThread()
{
     MessageBox(L"Does not compile", L"Would it even work?", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
}
```

The compile errors are "Error: argument of type "const wchar_t*" is incompatible with parameter of type "HWND"

and

Error: argument of type "long" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"

Comment: You are probably confusing [`CWnd::MessageBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa249432%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) method, and [`MessageBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: I'll take anything that pops up a box and prompts the user with my custom message!

Comment: Use [AfxMessageBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as6se7cb.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

`populateFilesThread` is not part of the class and therefore has no access to local variables. Hence, it cannot use the `MessageBox` overload [`CWnd::MessageBox(LPCTSTR, LPCTSTR, int)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=msvc-160#messagebox) that implicitly uses the `m_hwnd`, you have to use [`::MessageBox(HWND, LPCTSTR, LPCTSTR, int)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox) what also explains your error message you get.

You can safely pass `nullptr` as HWND.